# cocos2d-x runs on windows platform fine, but on android crashes

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I've been paid so much time debuging it, but I can't find any solution for the bug,
the following code always crashing on my galaxy S2 ( runs on android 4.1.2),
I develop with cocos2d-x 2.1.5,I avoid using autorelease,release,retain.. in onHttpRequestCompleted() functions, but it still not work on my device.

help me,please!
Here is my code:

```
#include "WuXiaUpdateScene.h"
#include "base64.h";
#include "FileOperation.h";
#include <algorithm>
#include "WuXiaLoginScene.h";
#include "WuXiaProgressBar.h"
#include "WuXiaServer.h"
#include "WuXiaMsgBox.h"
#include "StringHelper.h"

USING_NS_CC;

CCScene* WuXiaUpdateScene::scene()
{
    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    WuXiaUpdateScene *layer = WuXiaUpdateScene::create();

    // return the scene
    return (CCScene*)layer;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool WuXiaUpdateScene::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !CCLayer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }

    CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

    this->setFlag(UPDATE);

    /////////////////////////////
    // 3. add your codes below...
    fileCount = 0;
    fileUpdated = 0;
    CCLabelTTF * checkupdatesTTF = CCLabelTTF::create("Checking updates","Arial",22);
    checkupdatesTTF->setTag(1);
    checkupdatesTTF->setPosition(CCPoint(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2));
    this->addChild(checkupdatesTTF);

    // 建立 progress bar
    WuXiaProgressBar * progressBar = WuXiaProgressBar::create();
    progressBar->setTag(2);
    progressBar->setPercentage(0);

    status = Updating;

    connect();

    return true;
}

void WuXiaUpdateScene::onEnter()
{
    CCLayer::onEnter();
    this->schedule(schedule_selector(WuXiaUpdateScene::onUpdateCompleted),0.5);
}

void WuXiaUpdateScene::onHttpRequestCompleted(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient* client, cocos2d::extension::CCHttpResponse* response)
{
    std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();
    char* cString = new char[buffer->size()];
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<buffer->size();i++)
    {
        sprintf(cString+i,"%c",(*buffer)[i]);
    }

    std::string sString = cString;
    if (response->isSucceed() && sString.find("SUCCESS") != string::npos &&  sString.find("#SUCCESS") != string::npos)
    {
        if (sString.find("NO_UPDATES") != string::npos)
        {
            CCLabelTTF * checkupdatesTTF = (CCLabelTTF*)this->getChildByTag(1);
            if (checkupdatesTTF)
            {
                checkupdatesTTF->setString("No updates");
                status = Updated;
            }
            return;
        }

        vector<string> fileParts = StringHelper::Split(cString,"#");
        std::string writablePath = cocos2d::CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();
        std::vector<std::string> vPaths = std::vector<std::string>();
        vPaths.push_back(writablePath);
        cocos2d::CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(vPaths);


        vector<string> fileList = StringHelper::Split(fileParts.at(3).c_str(),",");
        CCLabelTTF * checkupdatesTTF = (CCLabelTTF*)this->getChildByTag(1);
        char* cFileCount = new char[5];
        sprintf(cFileCount,"0/%d",fileList.size());
        string count(cFileCount, cFileCount+strlen(cFileCount));
        string wstr;
        wstr.append("There're ");
        wstr.append(count);
        wstr.append(" files need to be updated.");
        checkupdatesTTF->setString(wstr.c_str());

        version = fileParts.at(1);
        fileCount = fileList.size();
        for (int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
        {
            cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest* request = new cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest();
            std::string version="0";
            char* url= new char[1024];
            sprintf(url,"%s",fileList.at(i).c_str());
            request->setUrl(url);
            request->setRequestType(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
            request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(WuXiaUpdateScene::onFileDownloaded));
            cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
            request->release();
            delete url;
        }

        CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
        CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

        WuXiaProgressBar * progressBar = (WuXiaProgressBar*)this->getChildByTag(2);
        progressBar->setPosition(CCPoint(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2-50));
        this->addChild(progressBar);
    }   
}

void WuXiaUpdateScene::onFileDownloaded(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient* client, cocos2d::extension::CCHttpResponse* response)
{
    WuXiaProgressBar * progressBar = (WuXiaProgressBar *)this->getChildByTag(2);
    std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();

    cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest *hr = response->getHttpRequest();
    const char * url = hr->getUrl();

    int len = strlen("7a30a48c-bd38-46b2-bb38-4afb79ac89abi.png");
    char * fileName = new char[len+1];
    memcpy( fileName, &url[strlen(url)-len], len );
    fileName[41] = '\0';
    FileOperation::saveFile(fileName,buffer);


    progressBar->setPercentage((++fileUpdated)/fileCount*100);

    if (fileUpdated == fileCount)
    {
        // 取得版本
        char* versionFile = "version.cfg";

        // 儲存版本資訊
        FileOperation::saveFile(versionFile,(char*)version.c_str());

        CCLabelTTF * checkupdatesTTF = (CCLabelTTF*)this->getChildByTag(1);
        checkupdatesTTF->setString("Update finished.");

        status = Updated;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        CCLabelTTF * checkupdatesTTF = (CCLabelTTF*)this->getChildByTag(1);
        char* cFileCount = new char[5];
        sprintf(cFileCount,"%.0f/%.0f",fileUpdated,fileCount);
        string count(cFileCount, cFileCount+strlen(cFileCount));
        string wstr;
        wstr.append("there're ");
        wstr.append(count);
        wstr.append(" files need to be updated.");
        checkupdatesTTF->setString(wstr.c_str());
    }
}
// connect to server and get file list to update
void WuXiaUpdateScene::connect()
{
    cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest* request = new cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest();
    std::string version="0";
    char* url= new char[1024];

    std::string versionFile = "version.cfg";
    if (FileOperation::isFileAvaiable(versionFile))
        sprintf(url,"%sgetUpdateFiles.aspx?text=%s",WuXiaServer::PrimaryServer,base64_encode(FileOperation::readFile(versionFile)).c_str());
    else
        sprintf(url,"%sgetUpdateFiles.aspx?text=%s",WuXiaServer::PrimaryServer,base64_encode("0").c_str());
    request->setUrl(url);
    request->setRequestType(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
    request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(WuXiaUpdateScene::onHttpRequestCompleted));
    cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
    request->release();
    delete url;
}

// switch screen whem update completed
void WuXiaUpdateScene::onUpdateCompleted(float dtTime)
{
    if (status != Updated)
        return;

    this->unschedule(schedule_selector(WuXiaUpdateScene::onUpdateCompleted));

    CCScene * scene  = WuXiaLoginScene::scene();
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(CCTransitionFade::create(1,scene));
}@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I correct my answer, it's a memory issue. 
char* cString = new char[buffer->size()]; can not store enough char for "buffer",
char* cString = new char[buffer->size()+1]; is correct,
I did not consider the empty char at the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that all the resources loaded while loading from android? Windows platform and android platform might have different resolution, and if you have loaded your resources according to resolutions, then check if all the resources are availble.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying me.

I've resolve this problem, the problem may cause by Visual Studio IDE, I remove some remarks it now works fine. I don't know why when I just add new .cpp and .h files to my project same problem may occur again, but to remove or add some codes to some pages, it works, very weird.